# Find most favorite products from a large table on SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

For SQL server, I have a table with

```
CostumerID  TITLE   DATE
1   m1  1999-05-08
1   m1  2000-07-10
1   m1  2001-12-11
1   m2  2008-03-20
1   m2  2005-09-05
1   m2  2011-07-08
1   m3  2006-07-22
1   m3  2009-01-19
1   m3  2012-02-18
2   m1  2007-09-28
2   m1  2010-11-19
2   m1  2009-08-09
2   m2  2010-04-22
2   m2  2008-10-16
2   m2  2010-07-22
2   m3  2013-07-31
2   m3  2011-01-11
2   m3  2010-02-20
3   m1  2010-04-07
3   m1  2011-06-11
3   m1  2010-11-09
3   m2  2013-08-21
3   m2  2014-07-19
3   m2  2015-12-29
3   m3  2011-04-17
3   m3  2014-01-31
3   m3  2012-09-19
2   m3  2010-02-03
…
```

Q1: I need to find the CostumerID that has consumed a product in Jan and Feb.

```
Select a.CostumerID  
From 
(Select distinct CostumerID  from theTable  where month(date) = '2') as a
Inner join 
(Select distinct CostumerID  from theTable where month(date) = '1') as b
On a.CostumerID  = b.CostumerID
```

Q2: Also, I need to find the most favorite one in all products that are consumed at the first time by each costumer.

```
Select b.title, count(b.title) as cnt
from
(
Select a.CostumerID , min(a.date) as earliestDate
from [DJX_test1].dbo.ama_services  as a 
group by a.CostumerID 
) as c
inner join [DJX_test1].dbo.ama_services  as b
on b.CostumerID = c.CostumerID and b.[date] = c.earliestDate
group by b.title
order by cnt desc
```

The table size may be large with 10+ millions rows. 
Are there better  queries without using subqueries ? 
Also, how to estimate a query's performance without running it ?

thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad.  I'd suggest that you start with a simpler question.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT costumerID
FROM theTable
WHERE month(date)='1' OR month(date)='2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1: I need to find the CostumerID that has consumed a product in Jan and Feb.

```
SELECT costumerID
FROM theTable
WHERE month(Convert(date,[date]))='1' OR month(Convert(date,[date]))='2'
```

Q2: Also, I need to find the most favorite one in all products that are consumed at the first time by each costumer.

You can easily achieve it by using dense_rank() function as below.

```
;with cte as
(
    select costumerID,title,date,
    dense_rank() over (partition by costumerid order by convert(Date,[date])) as rn
    from theTable
)
select * from cte where rn=1
```